# When did US federal government's revenue exceed combined state and local revenue?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Approximately when did the US federal government's revenue become larger than state and local revenue?

Even after the Constitution in 1787 the federal government's revenue was still much smaller than local. When did it become larger? Was it in the 1910s after the income tax, or only post WW2?

Basically, when did the US federal government's taxation power become more powerful than state+local?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I am not convinced the first sentence in your second paragraph is actually true.  I found [this (see table 1)](http://econweb.umd.edu/~wallis/mypapers/ptfinal.pdf), says that revenue at the national level was always higher than the state level.  Do you have a reference that shows otherwise, or is this just your supposition?   (Remember that excise taxes always existed at the national level, and were lucrative.)

Comment: Thanks @GorttheRobot. Actually what I'm really interested in is when the federal government became more powerful than state+local combined, which from Table 1 happened with WW2 - and the federal government never cut back its power.